# How to select the first element of each sublist in a list with Python?

Tags: python, list, arraylist, sublist

I have two lists with same shape:

```
 x = [[array([1.39555504e-06, 3.92652210e-04, 1.25352408e-01, 2.14678565e+01])],
 [array([1.67217238e-07, 3.88075043e-04, 1.26022677e-01, 2.41765099e+01])],
 [array([6.95260542e-07, 3.86892681e-04, 1.25952180e-01, 2.39032518e+01])]]
```

and

```
 sd_x = [[array([2.20316800e-06, 3.16566115e-06, 5.58783598e-04, 2.23978679e+00])],
 [array([2.15490637e-06, 3.13506583e-06, 5.47878385e-04, 2.22232169e+00])],
 [array([2.15498845e-06, 3.12207305e-06, 5.50507349e-04, 2.25939186e+00])]]
```

I need to calculate the mean value between the i-th element of each sublist (e.g. the mean btw the first element of each sublist: 1.39555504e-06, 1.67217238e-07, 6.95260542e-07] and the standard deviation on the mean, taking into account that the sd_x list contains standard deviations.
For the mean I wrote this code that works:

```
mean = np.array([np.mean(list(np.array(fit_sin).T[0])),np.mean(list(np.array(fit_sin).T[1])),\
                np.mean(list(np.array(fit_sin).T[2])),np.mean(list(np.array(fit_sin).T[3]))]);
```

However, I don't know how to define the standard deviation.
If i = len of each sublist (=4) , and j = len of the list (=3), I need to calculate:
st_dev= sqrt (sum (x[ij]/sd_x[ij])**2 )

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you want a column of a `numpy.ndarray`. To do so you can use `the_array[:, col]` where `col` is the column number (`0` in your example). `np.mean(sd_x[:, 0])` will return mean of first column.

Comment: What you're doing doesn't make sense.  You don't average a number and a standard deviation of its population.  What does `x` contain?  Is `x` the mean of a dataset and `sd_x` the standard deviation?  If `sd_x` is the standard deviation, then what you are trying to compute?